# Best practices for Terraform for deploying different environments to different azure subscriptions

Tags: azure, terraform

I have the following situation:
I have 2 azure subscriptions in the same organisation: production and development
I have 3 environments:
production which should be deployed to the production subscription
acceptance which should be deployed to the development subscription
development which should be deployed to the development subscription

I have a remote state storage account in the development subscription

I have created an script that deploys correctly to the development environment and connects to the state storage on the development subscription
I wanted to create 3 different workspaces for the different environments and have different settings.
but when I set the subscription to production terraform can't connect to the state storage on the development subscription.

Should I now have a second state storage account on the production account?

Comment: The short answer is yes. You can do cross account stuff so your state is held in a different account to the resources you are creating but this overcomplicates things and now means your production state is held in a development account which should be a major red flag for you.

Comment: So this isn't a best practice.
It is an operational demand to separate the production and development environment in different subscriptions. I believe they have different sla's.
What can I do to remove this red flag?

Comment: Just create a state storage account in the production account and use that for production resources.

Comment: the storageaccount name demands that it is unique. That means the production and development backend can't have the same name. Is there someway to make the backend name variable?

Comment: Either use partial config or just define the backend differently